Update or access Pandas DataFrame via API extension register_dataframe_accessor
I would like to edit a dataframe through the `register_dataframe_extension` available in the pandas API.
For example, I would like that that, provided the following code:
import pandas as pd

@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        # self._validate(pandas_obj)
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    @property
    def center(self):
        # return the geographic center point of this DataFrame
        lat = self._obj.latitude
        lon = self._obj.longitude
        return (float(lon.mean()), float(lat.mean()))

    def plot(self):
        # plot this array's data on a map, e.g., using Cartopy
        pass

    def ingest_sample_data(self):
        # define a sample DataFrame with latitude and longitude data
        self._obj = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "latitude": [0, 15, 30, 45, 60],
                "longitude": [0, 15, 30, 45, 60],
            }
        )
        return self._obj

Calling the ingest_sample_data method would update the original data.
What happens instead is that the dataframe remains unchanged.
Therefore, this:
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.geo.ingest_sample_data()
print(df)

returns an empty dataframe.
There is a prevoius question that is related to this one (Access pandas DataFrame from pandas accessor), but it is rather old and maybe there have been improvements.

You need to use df = df.geo.ingest_sample_data() as the function returns the DF not changes it in-place.

Overwriting df is not interesting to me, because I want to preserve all the possible other attributes of the pandas accessor. Imagine that I have a self.edited = False in __init__ and that this value is set to True by ingest_sample_data. By setting df = df.geo.ingest_sample_data() the value of df.edited would be again False.

You need to rethink your code. BTW there would be no attribute df.edited; tt would be df.geo.edited just as it is now df.geo.centre

Yes, that was a typo. How would you suggest to rethink such code, then? It seems very logical to me, I can't think of something more straightforward.

See suggested Answer below.

The complications you described arise from you creating an empty DF and then within geo creating another DF with sample data. Hence the need to accept the returned DF as in my comment. What (I think) you intended is to modify the original DF as shown below and not return a different DF:
import pandas as pd

@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        # self._validate(pandas_obj)
        self._obj = pandas_obj
        self.edited = False

    @property
    def center(self):
        # return the geographic center point of this DataFrame
        lat = self._obj.latitude
        lon = self._obj.longitude
        return (float(lon.mean()), float(lat.mean()))

    def plot(self):
        # plot this array's data on a map, e.g., using Cartopy
        pass

    def ingest_sample_data(self):
        # extend DataFrame with latitude and longitude data
        self._obj["latitude"] = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60]
        self._obj["longitude"] = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60]
        self.edited = True

df = pd.DataFrame()

print(df.geo.edited)
df.geo.ingest_sample_data()
print(df.geo.edited)
print(df.geo.center)

gives:
False
True
(30.0, 30.0)

